# How to make the selectbox value to be selected based on the value retrieve from cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am able to get the value stored in the session. Now I want to show the cookie value in my select box as selected value.

I tried with the below code, but unfortunately my cookie value is not getting selected.

Please help me to solve my issue.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){  
            $('#continue').click(function() {
                 var singleValues = $("#select_letter").val(); 
                $.cookie("language", singleValues); 
            }) 

    alert($.cookie('language')); //getting the correct value which are set in cookie

    $('#select_letter option[value="'+$.cookie('language')+'"]').attr('selected','selected');       
           //This is not working,Not setting the cookie value as selected

        });
    </script>  
        </head>
        <body> 
            <select id='select_letter'>
                <option>Java</option>
                <option>C</option>
                <option>php</option>
                <option>python</option>
                <option>c sharp</option> 
            </select> 
            <input type="button" id='continue' value="Save as default value"/>                
                   <!-- On click of this link the current page will load -->
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: The problem isn't your JavaScript, it's your HTML (using your current JavaScript anyway). You're trying to select using the attribute `[value=]` selector, but the `value` attribute on your options isn't set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be "value" in each option

```
<select id='select_letter'>
    <option value="Java">Java</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="php">php</option>
    <option value="python">python</option>
    <option value="c sharp">c sharp</option> 
</select>
```

And then

```
$("#select_letter").val($.cookie("language"));
```

Comment: I think your approach will also work without the value attribute on the options. I think it will be set to the text of the options if it is not set manually

Answer (score 1):

You can set the selected value using the following code

```
$('#select_letter').val($.cookie('language')).attr('selected', true);
```

Comment: Yes, I just saw, that Willy answered while I was still typing.